# puppet dependency from other class in other file

Tags: puppet

I'm using puppet to auto-provision servers on a cloud infrastructure.
I split my manifests in several .pp's.

I have the following error:

> Could not find dependency Mehc_module::Filestructure::File[/someFolder/someSubFolder]

The relevant parts:

filestructure.pp

```
class mehc_module::filestructure{
file {
        "/someFolder/someSubFolder":
           ensure  => link,
           owner   => $mehc_module::users::WEBLOGIC_UID,
           group   => $mehc_module::users::WEBLOGIC_GID,
           target  => "/opt/user_projects",
           require => UserDefinedFolder["/someFolder"];
    }
```

packages.pp

```
class mehc_module::packages{
    require mehc_module::filestructure

    ...
    mehc_repo::package { "${common11rpm}" :
    ensure => present,
    require => [
        Mehc_module::Filestructure::File["/someFolder/someSubFolder"]
    ];
    }
}
```

Why does it give me the error?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your resource reference is not structured correctly. You just want to

```
require => File["/someFolder/someSubFolder"]
```

Resource references do not take the manifest context into account. Even if they would, the "full path" to the resource would be `Class[mehc_module::filestructure]/File["/someFolder/someSubFolder"]`. But that will not work either.

The plain `File["/someFolder/someSubFolder"]` reference is sufficient because each resource can only be defined once in the whole of your manifest (including all modules).

Note that it is often a better practice to just

```
require => Class["mehc_module::filestructure"]
```

as this will imply the above relationship ("depend on all resources declared in the class") without tying the implementation of `mehc_module::packages` to implementation details of `mehc_module::filestructure`.

A notable exception from this rule is cases where the class you depend upon declares a large number of resources, thus leading to graph complexity (with performance implications), and a heightened danger of dependency cycles. The [Anchor Pattern](http://projects.puppetlabs.com/projects/puppet/wiki/Anchor_Pattern) helps with those cases.